# Why can't I see the parameters for my script in PowerShell?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

I'm working on a script that will effectively take the time and any input I provide it and spit it out on to an existing text file.

The parameters I created were $Input and $logPath. $Input should be able to take piped input or use "-Input" while the $logPath parameter would require "-logpath".

I'm not sure what I've done wrong since I can't see those switches when using auto complete in the ISE. If I try to pipe input I get:

> "Out-LogFile : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for
>   the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or
>   the input and its  properties do not match any of the parameters that
>   take pipeline input. At line:1 char:10"

If I try to stick to the switches instead of piping input I can use one but once I've input one I can't use the second switch.

Here is my function, any help is appreciated:

```
function Global:Out-LogFile {
    #Planned function for outputting to a specified log file.
     <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Adds to log files.

    .DESCRIPTION
    Updates a specified log file with a new line. The log file must already exist. See: Get-help New-LogFile

    .PARAMETER logPath
    Specifies a path for your new log (including file name).

    .EXAMPLE
    Get-ChildItem C:\ | Out-LogFile
    Piped input.

    #>

    [CmdletBinding()]

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                  ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True,
                  HelpMessage="input to append to logFile",
                  ParameterSetName='Input')]
        [string[]]$Input,


        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                  HelpMessage="Please enter the path to your log file",
                  ParameterSetName='logPath')]
        [string]$logPath
    )

    #Check to see that $logpath physically exists as a log file.
    Try {
        Write-Verbose Checking for existing log file.
        gi -Path $logPath -ErrorVariable $logPathError | Out-Null
    }

    Catch {
        throw "quitting! logPath does not exist, did you use the -logpath parameter? see: $logPathError"
    }

    #Create new time object, give it properties of Hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
    Try {
        Write-Verbose "Creating Time object for recording log timestamps"
        $time = New-Object PSObject -ErrorVariable $timeError
        $time | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hours -Value (Get-Date).Hour
        $time | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Minutes -Value (Get-Date).Minute
        $time | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Seconds -Value (Get-Date).Second
        $time | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Milliseconds -Value (Get-Date).Millisecond
        #declare "currentTime" variable used to place timestamps in log files. 
        [string]$currentTime = $time.Hours.ToString() + ":" + $time.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + $time.Seconds.ToString() + ":" + $time.Milliseconds.ToString() + "   "

    }

    Catch {
        throw "Can't create PSObject: time. See: $timeError"
    }

    Try {
        #Append data to log file
        Write-Verbose "Writing line to log file"
        [string]$currentTime + [string]$Input >> $logPath

    }
    Catch {
        throw "Quitting! Can't write to log file"
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling the function that's producing the error?

Comment: @mjolinor  
"test" | Out-logFile -logPath 'C:\LogFile.txt'  

It's really two things that are failing though, both the piping of information and the switch after the function call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have specified different parameter set names for `$Input` and `$logPath`. This effectively means that they are mutually exclusive and PowerShell will not let you use both at the same time (this is why they are not showing up in the ISE's autocomplete). Since you always want to use both at the same time in this case, there's really no need to specify custom parameter sets at all.

### Other things to note:

While I have you here let me just point out a few other things that may be issues:

You've named your input parameter `$input`, which you shouldn't do because `$input` is a pre-defined/auto-generated variable in PowerShell (specifically, `$input` is an enumerator object that provides access to the current pipeline) so giving a function parameter the same name could cause your script to behave in unexpected ways.

For example, if you try to pass a value to the parameter manually like this:

```
Out-LogFile -Input "string1" -logPath test.txt
```

Your script will output nothing because `$input` refers to the pipeline which doesn't have anything in it in this case. I suggest renaming `$input` to `$Message` or `$InputObject`, which is consistent with other `Out-` cmdlets.

---

This block has a couple of issues:

```
    Try {
        Write-Verbose Checking for existing log file.
        gi -Path $logPath -ErrorVariable $logPathError | Out-Null 
    }
    Catch {
        throw "quitting! logPath does not exist, did you use the -logpath parameter? see: $logPathError"
    }
```

Firstly, it will always throw an exception because your `Write-Verbose` text is not in quotes and so rather than the entire sentence being treated as a string, the word "Checking" is passed to `Write-Verbose`'s `Message` parameter and then "for" is passed to the next positional parameter that accepts a string (which, of course, doesn't exist). As a result, you'll receive a 'ParameterBindingException` that says something along the lines of:

```
Write-Verbose : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'for'.
```

Or rather, you would see that exception, except you have caught it and are then throwing another exception in the catch block that says the script is quitting and that logPath doesn't exist.

But even if you fix the unquoted string on `Write-Verbose`, the script won't quit and won't throw your custom exception if `Get-Item` fails to find `$logPath`. This is because when `Get-Item` can't find an item, it throws an `ItemNotFoundException`.

In PowerShell, there are *Terminating Errors* and *Non-Terminating Errors*. `ItemNotFoundException`. is a ***non***-terminating error. Terminating errors always terminate the script (hence the name) but non-terminating errors are dealt with differently depending the current [`$ErrorActionPreference`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx). By default, the `$ErrorActionPreference` is set to "Continue" which essentially means that when a non-terminating exception is thrown, the error is shown and the script continues; it isn't caught by a try-catch block.

A better way of determining whether the file exists is via the [`Test-Path`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx) cmdlet:

```
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $logPath))
    {
        throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException]("Could not find the file specified in logPath")
    }
```

---

This entire block is unnecessary (and a very roundabout way of getting a time string):

```
    #Create new time object, give it properties of Hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
    Try {
        Write-Verbose "Creating Time object for recording log timestamps"
        $time = New-Object PSObject -ErrorVariable $timeError
        $time | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Hours -Value (Get-Date).Hour
        $time | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Minutes -Value (Get-Date).Minute
        $time | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Seconds -Value (Get-Date).Second
        $time | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Milliseconds -Value (Get-Date).Millisecond
        #declare "currentTime" variable used to place timestamps in log files. 
        [string]$currentTime = $time.Hours.ToString() + ":" + $time.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + $time.Seconds.ToString() + ":" + $time.Milliseconds.ToString() + "   "

    }

    Catch {
        throw "Can't create PSObject: time. See: $timeError"
    }
```

The easiest way to get a date/time string in a particular format is to call the [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on a `DateTime` object. In the parentheses, we can specify a [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) format. `Get-Date` returns a `DateTime` object so we can just write:

```
$currentTime = (Get-Date).ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") + "   "
```

Which basically does the same thing except that it's less work for both you and PowerShell.

---

Finally, there's not really any reason to enclose your write operation in a try-catch block. If the write operation were to fail (due to the file being read-only, for example) that would be a non-terminating error and wouldn't be caught by your catch anyway.